# Asp.Net textbox TextChanged event is not firing in sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

there's no event fired when TextBox changed :
  jQuery tested and work fine:

```
      <SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" 
          Name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/content/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" 
              runat="server" />

          $(document).ready(function () {

               $("#fbn").change(function () {
                  alert("fired");
               });
          });


    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fbn" OnTextChanged="FilterByName" 
                     AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better way of doing this.

Remove the OnTextChanged from the TextBox.

Then replace  $("#fbn") with $('#' + '<%= fbn.ClientID %>')

The ID it shows in server side is different when the HTML code is rendered. So it will not hit from the jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fbn" CssClass="fbn" OnTextChanged="FilterByName" 
                     AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fbn").change(function () {
        alert("fired");
    });
 );
```

You can also just register the event on the control as Chromanin suggested.

Another option is to use server tags to print the ID into the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<$= fbn.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        alert("fired");
    });
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong attribute. OnTextChanged is for serverside event handling. You need the clientside  event.

Use onchange instead.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fbn" onchange="FilterByName()" 
                     AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks first. but  i attached the event automatically in javascript

Answer (score 0):

`AutoPostBack` will cause a server postback which won't allow the javascript function to fire.

Also the ID of the control does not stay that simple value. Here you have a few options, if you are not worried about hitting multiple text boxes, use classes.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fbn" CssClass="fbn" OnTextChanged="FilterByName" 
                     AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fbn").change(function () {
        alert("fired");
    });
 );
```

You can also just register the event on the control as Chromanin suggested.

Another option is to use server tags to print the ID into the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<$= fbn.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        alert("fired");
    });
 );
```

[AutopostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx)