# OnTextChanged Event not firing in SharePoint 2013 C#

Tags: development

I am trying to execute some code using Asp.net Textbox OnTextChanged Event but for some reason, its not firing at all.

I have `AutoPostback=true` set on the textbox.

anyone came across this problem?

Comment: There is same question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/asp-net-textbox-textchanged-event-is-not-firing-in-sharepoint-page or you may need to add some more detail in your question

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of Sharepoint sets the `_spFormOnSubmitCalled` to `true` and disallow more submits unless it is set back to false as occured in postback behavior.

So at `OnClientClick` event you should set `_spFormOnSubmitCalled` to `false;`

**The final code should look like**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" 

    OnTextChanged="btnGenerateReport_Click" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:setFormSubmitToFalse()" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="true" CausesValidation="false">
    Generate Report
</asp:TextBox> 

function setFormSubmitToFalse() {
    setTimeout(function () { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 3000);
    return true;
}
```

Also, try to add your Textbox at `Ajax updatePanel`

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: are you copy it then paste ? , try to add only this to your test pox OnClientClick="javascript:setFormSubmitToFalse()" then add this at head surrouded by java script function setFormSubmitToFalse() {
    setTimeout(function () { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 3000);
    return true;
}

Comment: Also, try to add your Textbox at `Ajax updatePanel`

Comment: i tried.but still not working

Comment: Hope to help you , so Should you provide me the code of textbox

Comment: OnTextChange event is not firing at all when i debug the code